# UiHandler doesn't work with SuggestBox SuggestionEvent

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am using a SuggestBox and trying to capture the SuggestionEvent that is fired when the user selects a Suggestion. I can do this with normal event handlers easily enough:

```
itemInputBox.addEventHandler(new SuggestionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuggestionSelect(SuggestionEvent event) {
                Window.alert(event.getSelectedSuggestion().getReplacementString());         
            }           
        });
```

That works fine, event fires with the correct replacement string. However, I like to use UiHandler whenever possible due to how much cleaner the code is. So I've tried the following:

```
@UiHandler("itemInputBox")
    void onSuggestionSelect(SuggestionEvent event) {
        Window.alert(event.getSelectedSuggestion().getReplacementString());
    }
```

But this results in the following errors:

```
[WARN] [jsonp] - Method 'getAssociatedType()' could not be found in the event 'SuggestionEvent'.


[ERROR] [jsonp] - Parameter 'SuggestionEvent' is not an event (subclass of GwtEvent).
```

I have a different UiHandler working correctly on the same SuggestBox so I am kind of confused where I'm going wrong:

```
@UiHandler("itemInputBox")
    void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
            Window.alert("Key up event firing.");
    }
```

I don't understand why one UiHandler fires correctly, while the other results in a error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SuggestionEvent does not extend GwtEvent instead it extends java.util.EventObject.

This is why it will not work with UiBinder. I will bring this up on the GWT contributer list to see if there is a specific reason for this. Right now I am just guessing that it was forgotten when moving to the new event system.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was losing my mind! Anyway, after posting this question I did some more research and found that the SuggestionHandler is deprecated anyway, so I switched over to using SelectionHandler and the corresponding UiHandler works perfectly.